# How do I return a 401 response in a SimpleJWT Custom Token when using the Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I would like to return a 401 message if the user is not enabled. When I try returning a response instead of a token it doesn't work which I understand to be because the serializer is expecting the token. How do I customise it to send a 401 response if the user is not enabled please?

My custom token class is as below:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        if user.is_enabled:
            token = super().get_token(user)
            # Add custom claims
            token['name'] = user.name
            token['gender'] = user.gender

            return token
        else:
            return Response({'detail':'Account not enabled'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

The URL root looks like:

re_path(r'^authenticate/',CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='authenticate'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me, it's a simple solution and gives me the result I need which is why I'm posting this as an answer.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        if user.is_enabled:
            token = super().get_token(user)
            # Add custom claims
            token['name'] = user.name
            token['gender'] = user.gender
            return token
        else:
            raise InvalidToken("User is not enabled.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return some symbol like None in Python from get_token if the user is not enabled and then override the get method of CustomTokenObtainPairView to return 401 if the value of get_token is None.

EDIT: Found a better way, move the check of is_enabled to the post request from the serializer. Below is the code.

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        # Add custom claims
        token['name'] = user.name
        token['gender'] = user.gender

        return token

from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        is self.request.user.is_enabled:
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return Response({'detail':'Account not enabled'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: When you return None it fails. I think what you're describing is what I've done in the code example, except that I'm returning a response, not None.

Comment: Yes, it fails because the None will go all the way up. That's why you will have to override the get/post method of view to intercept the None and return a different Response("Token not found).

Comment: Please can you post a code example as I don't quite understand how you implement that. 

Please see the answer, I posted, it gives me what I want and is simple to implement.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work, request.user is anonymous at the point where you have the if statement. If I print request.user before it returns "AnonymousUser".

Comment: AnonymousUser means the user is not logged in. Add IsAuthenticated permission to redirect users to login. See edited answer

Comment: The point is that this is meant to authenticate them and then issue the token so it looks like your method falls over where you have reference request.user because it hasn't issued the token yet.